# Why use bit shifting on values before writing to I2C?

Tags: python, bit-shift, i2c

I recently bought the PTZ-Camera-controller from arducam, and found a kind of API/Controller software on github (https://github.com/ArduCAM/PTZ-Camera-Controller). The module is integrated with I2C, and has several functions on different registers. I tried understanding the python-program, but I was confused by one line that occured several times in the program:

```
def read(self, I2C_address, register_address):
    value = self.bus.read_word_data(I2C_address, register_address)
    value = ((value & 0x00FF) << 8) | ((value & 0xFF00) >> 8)        #This one
    return value

def write(self, I2C_address, register_address, value):
    if value < 0:
        value = 0
    value = ((value & 0x00FF) << 8) | ((value & 0xFF00) >> 8)         #And this one
    return self.bus.write_word_data(I2C_address, register_address, value)
```

These can be used to, for instance, read or write to the cameras zoom-motor. The motor has 2317 steps, and the default span for the zoom-value is 0-18000. 
Which makes some sense, i guess, because if you for instance try writing 18000 = 0x4650, you get:

value = ((0x4650 & 0x00FF) << 8 | (0x4650 & 0xFF00) >> 8))

Which should equal 2400, by my estimation. Fairly close to 2317. However:

Why would they do this, instead of just having the input span from 0 to 2317?

Comment: It solely depends on the hardware on both sides master and slave. If your slave is BE (big endian) and master is LE (little endian) you need to properly pack byte array (out of two bytes) into 16-bit word. Same if master is BE and slave is LE.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that's flipping the order of two bytes in a 16 bit integer.
That's probably to convert from big endian to little endian, two different ways of representing integers. I think the controller uses big endian, PCs use little endian. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)